# RSS publishing on the wall of a facebook page

Tags: php, facebook

I am looking for an RSS feed published on a Facebook page and not a profile.

Currently, Facebook has removed the article on a lift fan page.

Can someone help me?

Comment: did you looked into manage_pages permissions ?